# Will a common mode choke and a FET switch cause issues in this circuit?

Tags: audio, switch-mode-power-supply, dac

I have a 12v 5A generic switch mode power supply which I use to power my USB DAC for streaming music through my PC to an amplifier and speaker combo. I have discovered that adding 6 x low ESR 4,700uf 16v electrolytic capacitors (28,200uf in total)  across the 12v input supply rails improves the stereo separation considerably and many instruments have a much clearer definition.

I want to put this into a proper metal case using a simple FET switch to add/remove the capacitors so I can compare the difference in real time. As I want to reduce any interference on the power line as much as possible, I'm also considering adding a common mode choke on the 0v and 12v rails to reduce as much noise and any 'pop and click' as possible. Without this addition, I can't hear any excess noise at present.

Would this be a useful addition to the design or would I be better off adding more capacitors? I'm considering using super capacitors but that would be a lot more expensive and I don't know if it would be any more effective than a design with regular capacitors. I'm aiming to squeeze as much performance out my DAC as possible without taking it apart and changing the output capacitors or op amps etc.

Comment: Without measurements, component choice (and positioning) is a complete guess. Do you know how much filtering you need, and at what frequencies?  Then, do you know what impedances the filter will be connected between? (Common example: the PSU already has a CMC in it, so adding one externally has relatively little effect i.e. the CMCs act in series and since a fairly large one is already in use, you would need a 10x+ larger one to see a significant decrease in noise.)

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams, you hit the nail on the head there. Unfortunately I don't have access to any decent test equipment to check how clean the supply is. I was thinking of a 1.6mh choke, but that will definitely not be 10x what is in the PSU so the answer would seem to be an unequivocal 'No'.

Comment: Then your options seem to be: leave it alone, or try things randomly and hope it's doing something. Which, keep in mind that if your only metric is "how it sounds", that's an extremely subjective measure, and might not lead to a meaningful improvement in the asked-for quantities. (Case in point: additive noise (hiss and crackle) has been ranked as preferable by audiophiles, in double-blind tests -- emulating the perception of often-dusty vinyl records.)

Comment: I might just try it as you say it will definitely be subjective and going by what you are saying the difference is probably going to be negligible (unless of course they have used an extremely low value CMC in the PSU). Unfortunately it is heat sealed so there is no non-destructive way of opening it to check the value. The original tiny PSU that came with the DAC would probably benefit from such an approach, there is a noticeable difference in sound quality between it and the beefier 5A one I replaced it with even before adding extra smoothing.